# «Авиационное предприятие — перевозчик» или «авиационное предприятие-перевозчик»?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, дефис-тире

Подскажите, как правильно: *авиационное **предприятие — перевозчик*** или *авиационное **предприятие-перевозчик***?

Comment: Где эти слова встретились? Выбор знака определяется контекстом.

Answer (score 2):

• При наличии прилагательного "авиационный", думаю, надо использовать тире (§ 154).

> В следующих случаях вместо дефиса должен употребляться знак тире.
> **1.** В сочетаниях с приложением, если одна из частей содержит пробел.
> Примеры с неоднословными определяемыми: *встреча с гостями Олимпиады — иностранцами, старшего лейтенанта — артиллериста, участников войны — инвалидов, о Михаиле Булгакове —– актёре, у научного сотрудника — космонавта.* Ср. *гости-иностранцы, лейтенант-артиллерист, воины-инвалиды, Булгаков-актёр, лётчик-космонавт.*

*Следовательно, **авиационное предприятие — перевозчик**, должно иметь организационно-правовую форму, присущую коммерческой организации...* (из комментария к ВК РФ).

•• Без прилагательного сочетание с однословным приложением пишется с дефисом:
[предприятие-перевозчик](https://www.slovarnik.ru/html-turist/p/predpri8tie-perevoz4ik.html), [компания-перевозчик](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA) (§ 120, б).

[Правила слитного, дефисного и раздельного написания](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)

Comment: Римма, а почему стоит запятая в комментарии к ВК после "перевозчик"? Ошибка в оригинале?

Comment: Да, это авторское оформление. Я видела эту запятую. Надо было, наверно, *(sic)* изобразить. Там  дальше с такой же непонятной запятой: *...а физическое лицо – перевозчик, должно быть зарегистрировано в качестве индивидуального предпринимателя*.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Так как, Саша, изображать или нет? Хочется знать твое *стрелецкое* мнение.

Comment: Да можно не надо :)  В комментах уже обсудили.